# How to add an ID that has just been deleted in a database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

Although this seems to be a pretty naive question to ask, I want to know about the way I can add a row with same ID that I have just deleted.

Let me make it clearer: suppose I have a table named Employee. The schema is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee 
(EmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY,
 EmployeeName varchar(255) not null,
 Designation varchar(255),
 Salary int);
```

Suppose I added a row with the following values, from my application:

```
EmployeeID -> 12
EmployeeName -> 'Lewis Montford'
Designation -> 'Accounts Officer'
Salary -> 8000
```

Now I have just performed a 'delete' operation on this record, from my application. I want to add a new record, of course from my application, but with the same ID. Something like this:

```
EmployeeID -> 12
EmployeeName -> 'Amanda Gresham'
Designation -> 'Senior Project Manager'
Salary -> 15000
```

I can't achieve this, as whenever I'm trying to add the new entry, 'EmployeeID' is automatically set to 13, instead of 12.

I want to know why I can't add a new entry with 'EmployeeID' set to 12 , and in what ways I can achieve that.

My database server is SQL Server 2012, and one important thing I'd like to mention is that 'EmployeeID' is an 'Identity', with 'Identity Increment' set to 1, and 'Identity Seed' set to 1, it is the primary key of this table and it is auto generated in my application.

The application I'm using to insert data is written in C#.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: So, you were incorrect when you said you specified the `EmployeeID` as 12 from your application, for the first insert? Anyway, if you're using identity columns properly, you shouldn't *care* what values they assign.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/24/sql-server-delete-truncate-and-reseed-identity/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you like to do that? I don't see any reason I would...
as to your question, you need to set the [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) to `ON` in order to specify the ID explicitly.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Employee ON

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (EmployeeID , EmployeeName ,Designation ,Salary  )
VALUES (12, 'Amanda Gresham','Senior Project Manager',15000)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Employee OFF
```

Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db7739/1) showing it in action

Comment: I tried your query and I keep getting this error: "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Employee' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Comment: @CrescentMoon - are you sure you've tried their query exactly as shown? And many people miss the `and` in that error message and only do one or the other of the requirements, rather than both.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I have tried the query exactly as shown. Is it something to do with the 'column list'? And what exactly did the error message mean by 'column list'?

Comment: `(EmployeeID , EmployeeName ,Designation ,Salary  )` before the keyword `VALUES` in the `INSERT` statement is the column list. And as you can see, I've added an sqlfiddle link to this answer which shows it working.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I forgot the (EmployeeID , EmployeeName ,Designation ,Salary ) before the keyword VALUES in the INSERT statement. Sorry I missed it, my bad. Thank you for explaining this to me.